# How to get the summation of iterated FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a function where it gathers values from specific input, this input is a part of FormArray within FormGroup (nested), the function is like this

```
addSales(){

 this.itemsArray.controls.findIndex(i => {

    this.totalPrice =parseFloat(i.get('price').value)

    console.log(this.totalPrice)

}
  )}
```

when adding multiple values like : 10,20,30 I get them printed like this

```
10
20
30
```

All what I need is returning the sum of these values, which is 60, would you please advise me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a philosophical perspective, there's a few things I'd recommend changing about the code:

1. follow a functional paradigm (no side effects)
2. use `reduce` instead of `findIndex` for generating a new value from iterating over an array (see [reduce docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

Right now the `addSales` function is performing two roles: (1) iterating through `itemsArray` and (2) updating `this.totalPrice` for each item in `itemsArray`. It makes the code harder to test because there's a lot going on.

Instead, I'd recommend doing the following:

```
addSales(): number {
  return this.itemsArray.controls.reduce((sum, i) => {
    sum += parseFloat(i.get('price').value)
    return sum;
  }, 0);
}

handleInputChange() {
  this.totalPrice = this.addSales();
}
```

Once `handleInputChange` is bound to your input change in the template, you will be able to more easily see what the code is doing (thereby debugging it easily).

Answer (score 0):

`+=` instead of `=` after `this.totalPrice`

Comment: in this case the result is :  10 30 60

Comment: Yeah, you're logging it for each iteration. If you only want to log the last output, put it outside of the loop.